# bootstrap-slider.js by seiyria not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

`bootstrap-slider.js` offered by seiyria not working in WordPress. It seems that resource file isn't linked properly. What am I missing here? Any idea?

Link Resource to WordPress(`functions.php`):

```
if (!function_exists('techcare_enqueue_scripts')):
function techcare_enqueue_scripts() {

    /*  Enqueue Scripts Begin */

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('modernizr');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/modernizr.min.js', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('classie');
    wp_enqueue_script('classie', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/classie.js', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('api');
    wp_enqueue_script('api', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('script-1');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-1', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJPGck9G3Pf4f912F_NyyEPFU9mOroxKo&callback=initMap', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('script-2');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-2', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('jquerymagnificpopup');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerymagnificpopup', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('smoothscroll');
    wp_enqueue_script('smoothscroll', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/SmoothScroll.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('apscrolltop');
    wp_enqueue_script('apscrolltop', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/ap-scroll-top.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('bootstrapdatepicker');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapdatepicker', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/bootstrap.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('wow');
    wp_enqueue_script('wow', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/wow.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('main');
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/main.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('jquerycounterup');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerycounterup', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/jquery.counterup.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('waypoints');
    wp_enqueue_script('waypoints', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/../cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('slick');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/slick.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('jqueryvalidate');
    wp_enqueue_script('jqueryvalidate', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('jqueryvalidateunobtrusive');
    wp_enqueue_script('jqueryvalidateunobtrusive', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_deregister_script('ajaxhandler');
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxhandler', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/scripts/ajaxhandler.js', false, null, true);


    wp_deregister_script('script-3');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-3', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJPGck9G3Pf4f912F_NyyEPFU9mOroxKo&callback=initMap', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('script-4');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-4', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('bootstrapslider');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.js', false, null, false);

    wp_deregister_script('bootstrapslider');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js', false, null, false);

    /*  Enqueue Scripts End */

    /*  Enqueue Styles Begin */

    wp_deregister_style('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('bootstrapdatepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapdatepicker', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/Css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('fontawesome');
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/font-awesome.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('animate');
    wp_enqueue_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/animate.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('effect');
    wp_enqueue_style('effect', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/effect1.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('style');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/style.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('responsive');
    wp_enqueue_style('responsive', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/responsive.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('rotate');
    wp_enqueue_style('rotate', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/rotate.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('normalize');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/normalize.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('set');
    wp_enqueue_style('set', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/set1.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('pricing');
    wp_enqueue_style('pricing', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/css/pricing.css', false, null, 'all');


    wp_deregister_style('bootstrapslider');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('bootstrapslider');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css', false, null, 'all');

    wp_deregister_style('intltelinput');
    wp_enqueue_style('intltelinput', get_template_directory_uri().
        '/countryCode/css/intlTelInput.css', false, null, 'all');


    /*  Enqueue Styles End */

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'techcare_enqueue_scripts');
endif;
```

Link Resource to WordPress (portion of code):

```
wp_deregister_script( 'bootstrapslider' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.js', false, null, false);

wp_deregister_script( 'bootstrapslider' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js', false, null, false);

wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrapslider' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css', false, null, 'all');

wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrapslider' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapslider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css', false, null, 'all');
```

Here's the HTML part :

```
<input id="web" data-slider-id='web' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0" />
```

JQuery Part :

```
        // With JQuery
        $("#web").slider();
        $("#web").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
        $("#webVal").text(slideEvt.value);
        $("#web1Val").text('$'+slideEvt.value);
        $("#web2Val").text('$'+slideEvt.value*10);
        $("#looking").text('a Web');
        });
```

Here's the demo page [link](http://techcarebd.com/techcare.beta/pricing/design-only/).

Comment: edit your question to explain what is not working

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your page. The code is a mess, full of html errors. In your question's code above you're queuing and dequeuing the script file four times, so it ends up once in the page header. In the page body you are also hardloading it four times.

The script that you include halfway the body then does not take into account that [WordPress loads jquery in nonconflict mode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#user-contributed-notes), meaning you cannot use the `$` selector. The latter may be the main reason why your slider doesn't work, but I suggest you also smooth out the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add scripts code after

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<scripts> //js code here </scripts>
```

section. Then it will be work fine.